# How to tell Mongo load a collection completely in memory

Tags: mongodb

We are using WiredTiger storage engine on Mongo 3.4

At the moment I have a collection with a single document in it.

When I query this document for the first time, Mongo does a disk IO and returns it nearly 150 ms. This response time decreases to 10 ms for the following requests.

However If I query a non-existent document from this collection, response time is always near 150 ms. Is there a way to improve this response time? Can I tell to Mongo in a way "You have already loaded the whole collection into memory. So you know that there is no such document. Yo DO not need to make disk IO again."

Comment: do you actually see io when querying not exisitng document? Or it's just same 150 ms?..

Comment: just 150 ms. It is my guess

Comment: Are you getting time by using explain or what?